# Does it make a difference whether you singular or plural version here?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> They learn so much in school but the moment they graduate, all the stuff they learned goes right out of their **head**/**heads**.

Does it make a difference whether you use the plural or the singular? Is the first option grammatically correct? Is there a difference in the meaning between the options?
Also, is it fine to use the singular version in similar contexts?

Comment: Yes it does. The word **they** is plural, so you must use **heads**. No, the first option is not grammatically correct. What contexts do you mean?

Answer (score -1):

It does make a difference. The plural "heads" is the only correct version in this instance because the **they** subject is assumed to be plural. However, in some cases, a subject of "they" might be used as it is the preferred pronoun for a non-binary student, and then the singular "head" would be the correct choice.

Assuming a preferred they pronoun isn't the case, you could still reword the sentence to allow the singular "head":

> A student learns so much in school but the moment they graduate, all the stuff they learned goes right out of their head.

In this instance, the singular **student** is used, and therefore the later they/their is also singular because the gender of the student is unspecified. If the subject were gendered (i.e. "A girl learns") then they/their would need to be replaced with she/her or he/his.